# Force Unity to save prefabs to disk

Tags: unity-game-engine

Using Unity 5.4.2.

I've created an editor script that implements an exporter for some prefab data when you press an export button. It recursively finds all the prefab files matching a certain type under its own directory and loads those prefabs so they can be exported in a custom manner.

The problem I'm having is that the prefabs on disk, that are loaded with

```
var prefab = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<GameObject>(file);
```

do not match the current state in the editor. That is if you have modified some of the prefab data in the editor, it is not actually saved to disk. Note that this does not require any objects to be added to a scene, I am just exporting data directly out of components attached to prefabs.

I have tried adding `AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();` to the top of my export function, which is supposed to save all the assets, but when I edit a value and then log the values loaded from the prefabs, they are not up to date. There are two (non-programatic) methods I have found so far that cause my exporter to be able to see the modified data:

- If I exit Unity and restart it, the prefabs appear to get saved at that point and the exporter sees the updated data.
- If I play and stop any scene, then export, the exporter can see the updated data, but oddly (according to git status) they have not been written to disk, so I suspect `LoadAssetAtPath` actually loads some cached version which is updated on 'play'.

Is there a way to force Unity to save everything to disk so that my exporter can operate on the most up to date values?

Comment: Note: I've actually solved the issue I was having, but the original question still stands because during my experimentation I've confirmed that `SaveAssets` doesn't actually do what it says on the tin and write things to disk. I also discovered that `LoadAssetAtPath` doesn't do what it says on the tin either (it actually returns the in-editor-memory version of the asset if it's already loaded).

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick

```
// Your changes go here

AssetDatabase.Save();
AssetDatabase.Refresh(ImportAssetOptions.ForceUpdate); // perhaps even ForceSynchronousImport?

// You loading should go here
```

For more information about `ImportAssetOptions` see this documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImportAssetOptions.html

Comment: This didn't work. Additionally I've found that playing a scene and stopping causes the updated assets to be seen by the exporter. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This does not answer the original question, but identifying and working around the cause may help anyone with the same/similar problem.*

My problem was when exporting computed-and-cached properties in components attached to the prefabs. My assumption that `LoadAssetAtPath` would load a fresh instance from disk was wrong, it returns the version already in editor memory, which means cached values aren't invalidated like they would be with a fresh load.

The solution I used was to never cache when running in the editor, using `#ifdef UNITY_EDITOR`.